# Python not recignizing module installed with pip

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the pybaseball package to practice learning python with some baseball data. I created a new python project with a python3.9 interpreter. I then installed pybaseball with:

```
C:\Users\sej16\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip install pybaseball
```

However, when I try to use the package (from pybaseball import statcast), I get a No module named 'pybaseball' error.

Edit: the following code produced the output below. Do I need to specify for pybaseball to be downloaded in the 'Scripts' directory?

```
import os
import sys
print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```

C:\Users\sej16\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/sej16/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/statcast.py

C:\Users\sej16\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Scripts

Comment: You need to show us some logs so we can try and see what is happening. More than likely you're trying to use the wrong Python executable than where you have installed Pybaseball

Comment: to test this try : `import os, sys` `print (os.path.dirname (sys.executable))`

Comment: Note that your pip installation uses `C:\Users\sej16\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe`, while your script execution uses `C:\Users\sej16\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Scripts\python.exe`. Those are different Python executables, and one won't see the packages installed by the other. You need to use the same Python executable for both installations and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments were helpful and installing pybaseball to the python executable for pythonProject4 solves the issue and it is now recognized